# MS Access Query to get unique rows based on a single column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query as:

```
SELECT MAX(SubmissionLog.ID), AccountTypes.Description, 
AccountContacts.FirstName, AccountContacts.LastName,  Accounts.Name, 
Accounts.StreetAddress, Accounts.MailAddress,SubmissionLog.EffectiveDate, 
SubmissionLog.ExpirationDate, StatusCodes.Description
FROM 
AccountContacts RIGHT JOIN (StatusReasons 
RIGHT JOIN ([JILL_MG utah sub query] 
RIGHT JOIN (StatusCodes 
RIGHT JOIN (Carriers 
RIGHT JOIN (AgencyLocations 
RIGHT JOIN (Brokers 
RIGHT JOIN (Agencies 
RIGHT JOIN (SubmissionLog 
LEFT JOIN (AccountTypes 
RIGHT JOIN (BusinessTypes 
RIGHT JOIN Accounts ON BusinessTypes.ID = Accounts.BusinessTypeID) 
ON AccountTypes.ID = Accounts.AccountTypeID) 
ON SubmissionLog.AccountID = Accounts.ID) 
ON Agencies.ID = SubmissionLog.AgencyID) 
ON Brokers.ID = SubmissionLog.BrokerID) 
ON (AgencyLocations.LocationID = Brokers.AgencyLocationID) AND 
(AgencyLocations.AgencyID = Brokers.AgencyID)) 
ON Carriers.ID = SubmissionLog.WinningCarrierID) 
ON StatusCodes.ID = SubmissionLog.StatusID) 
ON [JILL_MG utah sub query].SubLogID = SubmissionLog.ID) 
ON StatusReasons.StatusReasonID = SubmissionLog.StatusReasonID) 
ON AccountContacts.AccountID = Accounts.ID
WHERE   ( (AccountTypes.Description) Like "prospect" Or (AccountTypes.Description) Like "prev*") 
AND ( (SubmissionLog.EffectiveDate)>#12/31/2010#)  
AND  ((StatusCodes.Description) Like "not*")  
AND ((Accounts.dbType_id) In (15)) )
GROUP BY AccountTypes.Description, AccountContacts.FirstName, 
AccountContacts.LastName,  Accounts.Name, Accounts.StreetAddress, 
Accounts.MailAddress,SubmissionLog.EffectiveDate, 
SubmissionLog.ExpirationDate, StatusCodes.Description
ORDER BY Accounts.Name
```

It gives submission details based on Account Names. But we can have Account names repeated as we can have many submissions for an Account with different Effective Dates. But here i need to modify thr query so that I can get Account details with he most recent Effective date(having greatest value of SubmissionLog.Id) irrespective of unique combinations of Account Name with other columns. I jus want Account name with the recent effective date so that there is only one row per Account Name. I have used MAX(SubmissionLog.Id) to filter but due to unique combinations with other columns the Account Name is getting repeated as it has more than one combination with different values with other columns. Any workaround on this guys..??

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a subquery that takes the data from these three tables:

```
SELECT MAX(SubmissionLog.ID) MaxId, Accounts.Name
FROM 
SubmissionLog 
LEFT JOIN (AccountTypes 
RIGHT JOIN (BusinessTypes 
RIGHT JOIN Accounts ON BusinessTypes.ID = Accounts.BusinessTypeID) 
ON AccountTypes.ID = Accounts.AccountTypeID) 
ON SubmissionLog.AccountID = Accounts.ID
GROUP BY Accounts.Name
```

Then you can join your main query to this sub-query by Accounts.Name and SubmissionLog.ID to the MaxID and that way you will get the additional columns restricted by the max submission id

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion Cha. A bit extending the number of queries but yes , could be what I need. I'll try this and check. Thanks :)